# Which IP address in email headers is the sender's?

Tags: network, email

I have the headers from some emails I've received. There are several IP addresses in these headers. Which one belongs to the sender? Is the address in the headers reliable?

Example 1:

```
Delivered-To: highballer906@gmail.com
Received: by 10.60.17.1 with SMTP id k1csp74699oed;
        Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:20 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.50.7.1 with SMTP id f1mr461112iga.48.1371538580627;
        Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:20 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <jewelsbrookshunter@yahoo.com>
Received: from nm41-vm4.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com (nm41-vm4.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com. [98.138.120.220])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id l13si14092764igt.31.2013.06.17.23.56.20
        for <highballer906@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:20 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of jewelsbrookshunter@yahoo.com designates 98.138.120.220 as permitted sender) client-ip=98.138.120.220;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of jewelsbrookshunter@yahoo.com designates 98.138.120.220 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=jewelsbrookshunter@yahoo.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@yahoo.com
Received: from [98.138.90.51] by nm41.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 18 Jun 2013 06:56:20 -0000
Received: from [98.138.226.169] by tm4.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 18 Jun 2013 06:56:20 -0000
Received: from [127.0.0.1] by omp1070.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 18 Jun 2013 06:56:20 -0000
X-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-3
X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 174185.10454.bm@omp1070.mail.ne1.yahoo.com
Received: (qmail 91727 invoked by uid 60001); 18 Jun 2013 06:56:20 -0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo.com; s=s1024; t=1371538580; bh=liTWktiapaLjHdw+2TpVo5Asxk4qjy0W+vRDynxa69M=; h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; b=EYqUn7pMwJj5u38emYJUabh5GdDtZpb+5fc+seNp2LSGLoyH5b7H4Xi5s4VnsgGMV9quc/+eCX4MRGdE3vT0BNX2TtZGZFLmjWleroLYEiv9Qkn2ydReRdtQrCAoXlfje4LZJx5TRthkxyH5j6b0EZpt1l72ZJUjtjEB/ddpz3M=
DomainKey-Signature:a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws;
  s=s1024; d=yahoo.com;
  h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type;
  b=iJgA5kie62DmC4ZZKFHeIMStlbIEzfaGtdgMMcl3QSe9kEJB5yN+qMreDiaq4ZNwtxbGin13osmOGAKubmel9J4Z9p2PaWePYPbLB9092i1xPJIMHMl4QVZWogox5JWuaNGxD3R1YkBrUNFUl7StxywuUsPx6g1Ogsqmi5qy4c4=;
X-YMail-OSG: PrPru38VM1l9Vh.ARg8RlM27WxEx8CScPDJBiGPJviw8Ik6
 LPTA7jMAMP5wTi4lPDcQrSWfGGKkNf5r_gjNI_y1MoJXzaVtVYaALubMukxN
 BxWN9AiMb._7CNZNutAya549ZVjpN4Y8nD0HE8SuMKRT19wFjzyKxYJ1Wuzb
 KEetveoHoA.7h9Z4NmBod6v1PjYTKpekiZsp7iZ0UnTNCDyzS6O4AfzwZelw
 e2yXyk4lqu2KO0.IUq4rxedGZBFCZpfrKmOAOXGAo.aAcYDTn5uPMK6RvnTo
 TRcMa9qxA_hivYMgJ.WS3nw4vVP1B5dWgw.78hkphwW2ZG4_PtOiOAd963JH
 3NElG0aTlqrTkXJMka2fGyA4Q347aEtbR.wlrHiidyjhH2DANRuZVWFGvs23
 uiw7Rz5UzfBpvxOqFU02JZGPT.Z0Z82rUa_InzuvDAh38RvNVDkTU50WyHKa
 NwdmeW27StXE_JPUNWWIscOrFNRMRsGf_e7aD6TGBChWjcc8vmEC_VQVt4Jx
 QckpYdz9cjw--
Received: from [24.224.133.144] by web126202.mail.ne1.yahoo.com via HTTP; Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:19 PDT
X-Rocket-MIMEInfo: 002.001,CmkNCg0KDQpJIGtub3cgeW91ICYgeW91ciBsaWZlLCBjaXJjbGUgb2YgZnJpZW5kcywgZXRjIHRoZXJlZm9yZSwgSSBvbmx5IHNlZSBpdCBmYWlyIHlvdSBzaG91bGQga25vdyB5b3VyIGxpZmUgaXMgYSBnYW1lIGFuZCB5b3UncmUgc2FkbHkgYmVpbmcgcGxheWVkISBTZXJpb3VzbHkgbWFkZSBhIGZvb2wgb2YuIEV2ZXJ5b25lIHlvdSBrbm93LCBrbm93cyB0aGF0IEFubmEsIEFubmllIHdoYXRldmVyIHlvdSBjYWxsIHlvdXIgb2xkIHJvb21tYXRlLiBNZWV0IHlvdXIgaGFzYmFuZCB3aGVuIHNoZSB3YXMgYSABMAEBAQE-
X-Mailer: YahooMailWebService/0.8.147.553
Message-ID: <1371538579.88210.BPMail_high_noncarrier@web126202.mail.ne1.yahoo.com>
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:19 -0700 (PDT)
From: Jewels Brooks Hunter <jewelsbrookshunter@yahoo.com>
Subject: you need to jnow your life is a LIE
To: highballer906@yahoo.com, highballer906@gmail.ca, highballer906@gmail.com,
  highballer906@yahoo.ca
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Example 2:

```
Delivered-To: highballer906@gmail.com
Received: by 10.60.17.1 with SMTP id k1csp74699oed;
        Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:20 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.50.7.1 with SMTP id f1mr461112iga.48.1371538580627;
        Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:20 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <jewelsbrookshunter@yahoo.com>
Received: from nm41-vm4.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com (nm41-vm4.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com. [98.138.120.220])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id l13si14092764igt.31.2013.06.17.23.56.20
        for <highballer906@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:20 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of jewelsbrookshunter@yahoo.com designates 98.138.120.220 as permitted sender) client-ip=98.138.120.220;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of jewelsbrookshunter@yahoo.com designates 98.138.120.220 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=jewelsbrookshunter@yahoo.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@yahoo.com
Received: from [98.138.90.51] by nm41.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 18 Jun 2013 06:56:20 -0000
Received: from [98.138.226.169] by tm4.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 18 Jun 2013 06:56:20 -0000
Received: from [127.0.0.1] by omp1070.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 18 Jun 2013 06:56:20 -0000
X-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-3
X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 174185.10454.bm@omp1070.mail.ne1.yahoo.com
Received: (qmail 91727 invoked by uid 60001); 18 Jun 2013 06:56:20 -0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo.com; s=s1024; t=1371538580; bh=liTWktiapaLjHdw+2TpVo5Asxk4qjy0W+vRDynxa69M=; h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; b=EYqUn7pMwJj5u38emYJUabh5GdDtZpb+5fc+seNp2LSGLoyH5b7H4Xi5s4VnsgGMV9quc/+eCX4MRGdE3vT0BNX2TtZGZFLmjWleroLYEiv9Qkn2ydReRdtQrCAoXlfje4LZJx5TRthkxyH5j6b0EZpt1l72ZJUjtjEB/ddpz3M=
DomainKey-Signature:a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws;
  s=s1024; d=yahoo.com;
  h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type;
  b=iJgA5kie62DmC4ZZKFHeIMStlbIEzfaGtdgMMcl3QSe9kEJB5yN+qMreDiaq4ZNwtxbGin13osmOGAKubmel9J4Z9p2PaWePYPbLB9092i1xPJIMHMl4QVZWogox5JWuaNGxD3R1YkBrUNFUl7StxywuUsPx6g1Ogsqmi5qy4c4=;
X-YMail-OSG: PrPru38VM1l9Vh.ARg8RlM27WxEx8CScPDJBiGPJviw8Ik6
 LPTA7jMAMP5wTi4lPDcQrSWfGGKkNf5r_gjNI_y1MoJXzaVtVYaALubMukxN
 BxWN9AiMb._7CNZNutAya549ZVjpN4Y8nD0HE8SuMKRT19wFjzyKxYJ1Wuzb
 KEetveoHoA.7h9Z4NmBod6v1PjYTKpekiZsp7iZ0UnTNCDyzS6O4AfzwZelw
 e2yXyk4lqu2KO0.IUq4rxedGZBFCZpfrKmOAOXGAo.aAcYDTn5uPMK6RvnTo
 TRcMa9qxA_hivYMgJ.WS3nw4vVP1B5dWgw.78hkphwW2ZG4_PtOiOAd963JH
 3NElG0aTlqrTkXJMka2fGyA4Q347aEtbR.wlrHiidyjhH2DANRuZVWFGvs23
 uiw7Rz5UzfBpvxOqFU02JZGPT.Z0Z82rUa_InzuvDAh38RvNVDkTU50WyHKa
 NwdmeW27StXE_JPUNWWIscOrFNRMRsGf_e7aD6TGBChWjcc8vmEC_VQVt4Jx
 QckpYdz9cjw--
Received: from [24.224.133.144] by web126202.mail.ne1.yahoo.com via HTTP; Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:19 PDT
X-Rocket-MIMEInfo: 002.001,CmkNCg0KDQpJIGtub3cgeW91ICYgeW91ciBsaWZlLCBjaXJjbGUgb2YgZnJpZW5kcywgZXRjIHRoZXJlZm9yZSwgSSBvbmx5IHNlZSBpdCBmYWlyIHlvdSBzaG91bGQga25vdyB5b3VyIGxpZmUgaXMgYSBnYW1lIGFuZCB5b3UncmUgc2FkbHkgYmVpbmcgcGxheWVkISBTZXJpb3VzbHkgbWFkZSBhIGZvb2wgb2YuIEV2ZXJ5b25lIHlvdSBrbm93LCBrbm93cyB0aGF0IEFubmEsIEFubmllIHdoYXRldmVyIHlvdSBjYWxsIHlvdXIgb2xkIHJvb21tYXRlLiBNZWV0IHlvdXIgaGFzYmFuZCB3aGVuIHNoZSB3YXMgYSABMAEBAQE-
X-Mailer: YahooMailWebService/0.8.147.553
Message-ID: <1371538579.88210.BPMail_high_noncarrier@web126202.mail.ne1.yahoo.com>
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:19 -0700 (PDT)
From: Jewels Brooks Hunter <jewelsbrookshunter@yahoo.com>
Subject: you need to jnow your life is a LIE
To: highballer906@yahoo.com, highballer906@gmail.ca, highballer906@gmail.com,
  highballer906@yahoo.ca
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that formatting hurts my brain. :)

There are two answers I have for you.  The first is that you can't trust anything after your own mail exchanger.  In that event I would say:

```
Delivered-To: highballer906@gmail.com
Received: by 10.60.17.1 with SMTP id k1csp74699oed; 
Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:20 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.50.7.1 with SMTP id f1mr461112iga.48.1371538580627; 
Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:20 -0700 (PDT) Return-Path: 
Received: from nm41-vm4.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com (nm41-vm4.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com. [98.138.120.220]) by mx.google.com
```

So, my first answer is that it came from Yahoo for sure.  If we assume that we can trust all of the headers then the answer becomes:

```
Received: from [24.224.133.144] by web126202.mail.ne1.yahoo.com via HTTP; Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:19 PDT X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:
```

So, 24.224.133.144.

The same is true of the second message.

Comment: Just a second reminder that "seems to be true" is a very important phrase.  Forging email headers is trivial so you can only be absolutely sure of the first "Received: from" that comes from servers that you control or trust.  Anything before that is suspect.